# Famous hacker koan: who was it about, though?

Tags: education, history

Read this many years ago and can't remember who it was about. Nor can I remember the exact quote. The story goes:

> Famous computer scientist/professor is teaching a class. Student is having some problem w/ a machine and wants to reboot it, hoping to fix the issue. Professor chides him, saying something to the effect of "you can't expect rebooting to fix the problem unless you 'Truly Understand What Is Going On'". Professor then proceeds to reboot the computer and the issue resolves. ;)

Who was it?

Answer (score 1):

Tom Knight

https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_koan

The item titled "Enlightenment"

Thanks to reinierpost.

Comment: Wait a minute. First, we're told to turn the comment into an answer. When we do that, we're told not to. Can we make up our minds about this?

Comment: @reinierpost, the correct thing is to put answers in the answer (not as a comment).  If you see a comment and an answer that are duplicative, I encourage you to flag the comment as 'no longer needed'.  We generally discourage answering in a comment.  If you see a question that is answered in a comment, feel free to post your own answer with that material, then flag the comment as 'no longer needed'.

Comment: Thank you. I notice my comment is gone; I was going to remove it, so thanks.